# ArcGis Map Labelling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I have created a new field within one layer in Arcmap. and i have run some values and assigned each feature to a specific value inside the new field in the attribute table for the layer.

Now I am labeling for this layer and as i see, Arcgis have solved the overlapping issues for labeling the polylines features by its model.

I would like the Arcgis to solve the labeling overlapping issues for the polylines features by the weighted values, that i have created and added to the layer. Meaning that, i would like the Arcmap to give priority to each feature based on the value that it received from the field inside the attribute table.

I tried the Maplex, but i found out that you can choose the priority (High mod. low) for each layer and not for the features inside the layer.

Please can anyone give an idea how i can solve these problem. and if there is python or sql codes that can solve it, can you please give them to me.

Answer (score 3):

Under the label tab of the layer properties you can 'Define classes of features and label each class differently'.

[image]

An SQL query can be specified for each class. Each separate class will then appear under the 'Weight Rankings'

[image: wieght rankings]

You should be able to divide the feature class and apply different label weights this way.